# Dynamic header content in React

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I'm going to build a React app in which each page has its own header content(Header component my mean not head element), and its contents may not look alike(For example for search page we have a input on header and for single page we have single title and action buttons, just like a native app) and the number of pages is pretty large, but I don't know how to do it and I need guidance. I want to see if react has a convenient solution to implement this? Do I have to make a proprietary header component for each page? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a layout component and add a custom header component there.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Thanks, I'm new to react, Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use react-router for example, suppose you have two components 
`Header` and `Contact us` and you want to change the title/contents for both the components so you can do it this way.

Suppose this is your Header component :-

```js
import React from 'react';
import About from './components/About';

class Header extends React.Component {
    state = {
      title: this.props.title
    };


 render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Header;
```

And the other component you have `Contact us` which will be like this somewhat :-

```js
import React from 'react';

class About extends React.Component {

 componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ title: 'Contact us' });
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <article>Your contact us contents will be here..</article>  
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Contact;
```

Now you can use react-router to get the current pathname in your App.js component. Now based on this `current pathname` you can send the title as props to the header containing the name.

example :-

```js
title = () => {
    switch(this.props.location.pathname){
        case "contact":
            return "Contact us";
        case "signin":
            return "Sigin";
        default:
            return "app_name"
    }
}
```

Or the you can also use react-helmet package which is used to change the contents of header dynamically here is the link :-

https://dev.to/guimg/dynamic-document-head-with-react-helmet-28o6

Comment: Thanks, did you see the updated post? It is not just the title that has to be changed, but the whole content is needed to change.